# Why is my texture quality so poor when running a webGL build from unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I've imported a texture whose quality drops significantly in web builds.  I have the compression set to "none", and max size set as high as it will go,

[image]

with "Override for Web GL" left unchecked

[image]

The scaling is 1:1,

[image]

and in Project Settings > Quality, I have webGL set to "Ultra"

[image]

And still there's a visible difference in quality by comparison to running on desktop.  It's much more pixelated.  I've tried in both Chrome and Firefox.

Does WebGL have some hard limitation that desktop doesn't?  The image's native size is 948 x 1340

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have mip-mapping enabled on your textures? (in Advanced > Generate mip maps).
You should also consider using square power of two textures.

Comment: Ahhh, turning on the mip maps helped a lot! What do you mean when you said "consider using square power of two textures?"  Is there a setting somewhere that I should be changing?  Thank you so much, this has been a huge help already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the answer!  While the mip map helped by adding a slight blur, to smooth off the edges, the real issue was that the texture I was using was too large.  Under File > Build Settings > Player Settings, I could change the resolution.

Unfortunately, by making it large enough to see the whole texture clearly, it becomes too large to see without zooming out the page.  There doesn't seem to be a clean solution.  Resizing an image means loss in resolution, but at least now I know why it was looking the way it was out the other end.

Comment: Could you create a link/dropbox to the texture so we could test it out?

Comment: Update: the "clean solution" here was making the camera cover a larger area.  That way, the texture would be smaller in the screen without having been resized.